# Beta hat in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

While reviewing [King & Zeng paper](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf) on rare event data in logistic regression, I'm wondering what this term means?

[image]

Beta hat of the class 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the estimated intercept in the logistic regression. I.e.,

$$E(Y\vert \vec{x}) = p(\vec{x}),  \qquad 
\log\left(\frac{p(\vec{x})}{1-p(\vec{x})}\right) = \beta_0+\vec{\beta}_1^\top\vec{x} $$

See appendix B.4 and write $\tilde{\vec{x}} = (1, \vec{x}^\top)^\top$ and $\vec{\beta} = (\beta_0,\vec\beta_1^\top)^\top$